# Insert background color in PHP echo statement

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to correctly insert a hex color value equal to a variable, which I have placed inside HTML in an echo statement.  The goal is to change the `<div>`'s background color to the `$hexcolor` variable's value.  The `$hexcolor` variable works fine, outputs colors in a hex format (e.g. #000111), but the echo statement does not change the background color.

```
$hexcolor = "#$hexconvert";
echo '<div style=\"background:$hexcolor; height:10px; width:10px;\">Test</div>';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as

```
    $hexcolor = "#$hexconvert;";
    echo '<div style="background: '.$hexcolor.' height:10px; width:10px;">Test</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside strings surrounded by single quotes do not get expanded by PHP. If you use double quotes around the string you're trying to echo it will work. Like this:

```
echo "<div style=\"background:$hexcolor; height:10px; width:10px;\">Test</div>";
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for the difference between single and double quotes.